# How to change the local delivery of accounts?

Tags: postfix, dovecot, debian-jessie

I have noticed in my logs that Postfix cannot send emails to local accounts.

```
postfix/local[12775]: warning: maildir access problem for UID/GID=33/33: create maildir file /var/www/Maildir/tmp/1492097290.P12775.FQDN: Permission denied
postfix/local[12775]: warning: perhaps you need to create the maildirs in advance
postfix/local[12775]: 56ABC81A28: to=<www-data@FQDN>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file /var/www/Maildir/tmp/1492097290.P12775.FQDN: Permission denied)
postfix/qmgr[8037]: 56ABC81A28: removed
```

I have virtual domains configured, and they work correctly. I am able to successfully send emails from one account to another.

How to change the local delivery options of Postfix to another directory other than the `/var/www/`?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably caused by following conditions:

- You have set `home_mailbox = Maildir/`, which is optional pathname of a mailbox file relative to a local(8) user's home directory. (Default value is `empty` causing delivery to `/var/mail/user`.)
- User `www-data` has home directory `/var/www`, causing delivery to `/var/www/Maildir/`
- `/var/www` is default root folder for the web server and is owned by `root:root` (instead of `user:mail`), causing the `Permission denied` error.

The result is actually good. If Postfix could write to that directory, all mail received by www-data could be readable through http://example.com/Maildir/. The error message in the log *per se* isn't something you should fix, but you have to take some time to think your mail server overall configuration and what is the desired state:

- Is it necessary for user www-data (web server) to receive mail? Who will read it?
- If you have `virtual_alias_domains` for the domains you use, do you need `mydestination` and `local_recipient_maps` at all?
- If you do need delivery based on `/etc/aliases` in addition to your `virtual_alias_maps`, should you prevent some users to receive mail with `check_recipient_access`?
- Do you really [want to run own mail server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/why-you-may-not-want-to-run-your-own-mail-server)?  Do you have the [expertise & effort](http://blog.mailchannels.com/2015/10/should-i-build-my-own-mail-server)? [Security](http://library.ahima.org/doc?oid=99319#.WPEOyoiGPmE)?

**You should have all the basics together before accepting any mail from the wild Internet.**  Basic configuration of Postfix (just like this local delivery issue) is a crucial part of it.